Typescript distributive over mapped generics?
I know Typescript distributes generic types in conditionals, but why does it distribute when there is no condition?
type Box<U> = { [K in keyof U]: [U[K]] }; // a random mapping
type Objects = {a: 1, b: 2} | {a: 3, c: 4};

type Distributed = Box<Objects>;
type NotDistributed = { [K in keyof Objects]: [Objects[K]] }; // same mapping as Box<U>, but different result

Notice the difference between the 2 generated types:
type Distributed = {
    a: [1];
    b: [2];
} | {
    a: [3];
    c: [4];
}

type NotDistributed = {
    a: [1 | 3];
}

I searched but didn't find any explanation for this difference.

• TS type names are conventionally UpperCamelCase, not lower_snake_case. • Yes, homomorphic mapped types that operate on generic type parameters distribute over unions (as documented in the implementing PR at ms/TS#12447 where it calls it "isomorphic" instead of "homomorphic"). When you write [K in keyof Objects] and it isn't generic then it doesn't distribute (like how conditional types only distribute when checking generic type params). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

(see prev comment) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44850 is the canonical source btw

yes, by all means, write a reply! How did you find that PR? awesome. And yes, I know about the case convention for TS types, but sometimes I feel like breaking the rules, especially when they are not strict rules:)

I've edited this question to use normal naming conventions, since the point of the question has nothing to do with naming conventions, and at best it's a distraction. Of course you can name your types whatever and however you want in your own code, but Stack Overflow is for future readers also.

Yes, homomorphic mapped types (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?) operating on generic type parameters will distribute over unions in their type arguments, whereas mapped types on specific types will not. This behavior was implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#12447 (where it was called "isomorphic" as opposed to  "homomorphic"). It is intentional behavior, as described in microsoft/TypeScript#44850.
So Box<Objects> distributes over the union in Objects, while {[K in keyof Objects]: ⋯} does not.
